# netstandard1.0 /netstandard1.2 and LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm porting a simple library (without deps) to `netstandard1.0`. Probably easy for you guys, but I can't see why I'm getting this build error when targeting `netstandard1.0` on a simple class lib I have.

> CS1061    'string' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    MyProject..NETStandard,Version=v1.0

So, it seems is complaining about the `Any` method; an extension method part of the Linq libraries i presume. AFAIK, Linq is part of the NETStandard.Libary meta package for 1.0.

Code in question:

```
var numberString= "1234";
var isAllDigits = numberString.Any(t => !char.IsDigit((t))
```

My `project.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
       "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.0": { }
  }
}
```

Changing my project.json to `netstandard.1.2` resolves it, but afaik the Linq stuff is present in 1.0 and should be able to compile..?

Also, the portability tool ran fine and said I could target as low as `netstandard1.0` as well.

So:

**How can I tell `System.Linq` v.4.3.0 is not supported when creating libraries targeting netstandard1.0?**

Answer (score 1):

Since one idea of .net core is to keep the library is small as possible, linq and many extension methods are in a extra package.

Try installing [Install-Package System.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq/4.1.0).

Another thing i want to point out is the very helpful tool [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) which allows you to search for classes and find the corresponding .net core package. Very helpful for porting to .net core.

Comment: However: I'm referencing the "NETStandard.Library" meta package, which is dep on System.Linq.: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/

Answer (score 0):

That's a hidden bit. Look at the .NET Standard Matrix [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) and MSDN Article for [string.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx).

> ### Version Information
>
> - Universal Windows Platform: Available since 8
> - .NET Framework: Available since 3.5
> - Portable Class Library: Supported in: portable .NET platforms
> - Silverlight: Available since 2.0
> - Windows Phone Silverlight: Available since 7.0
> - **Windows Phone: Available since 8.1**

Notice the latest point. Since .NET Standard needs to run on all the supported platforms, it also must run on Windows Phone 8.1. But to target Windows 8.1 you need minimum .NET Standard 1.2. Hence, you can't target `netstandard1.0` if you want to use this method.

You can use `#if` preprocessor directives to remove it for NET Standard < 1.2 and use other function, or just implement it yourself (i.e. via `Regex`).

Comment: I'm including the NETStandard.Library meta package in my `dependencies`, which itself in it's netstandard1.0 version depends on System.Linq. 

If I cannot trust that the NetStandard.Library includes what it says - what use is it?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/

Comment: The meta packages aren't a magic bullet to use higher/newer APIs in old framework (its **not** like Androids "Support Library"). i.e. you still can't use `Task.Done` in `netstandard1.0` or `net45`, because this API was only added in .NET 4.6. This gonna get a bit more complicated with `netstandard2.0` where you will get more apis, but some of them may only work on certain platforms and you won't get compile time errors but they will rather throw `PlatformNotSupportedException` where you will need to know (w/o help of the UI) which API runs on which platform

Comment: Also as a side note, the API surface will be increased much with netstandard2.0. Many of the APIs that were unavailable in .NET Core will be available in netstandard2.0, but it will be a small breaking change though. Normally each of the netstandard versions will have all api of the previous plus new ones. 2.0 will have **less** than 1.6 and this is the breaking change. 2.1 however (which should be released at the same time as 2.0) will have 2.0 + removed 1.6 APIs back

Comment: When I ran the Portability tool targeting netstandard1.0, it complained about some methods, and I changed those to make the portability tool happy for netstandard1.0 support. After those changes, I got everything green in the reports. Fine. At build time however, it complained about one single method, `any`.  So, if I cannot trust 
the API portability tool nor the NETStandard.Library dependency list  what's the best way going forward for _knowing_ a given API, like LINQ, is available for a given netstandard version?

Comment: Hi, @Tseng - can you explain why I made System.Linq work for netstandard1.0 using the 4.0.0 version of System.Linq?  (as pr my answer here on SO)?

Not sure I get how that fits with what you just have explained.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got `netstandard1.0` support for my library including `System.Linq` as a dependency.

I did the following steps:

1. Remove the dep on `NETStandard.Library` and include those deps explicitly instead in my `project.json`
2. Start removing deps and verify that the project still builds for each removed dep.
3. Try to downgrade each package to the lowest possible version that still works.

During the downgrade in 3., I finally got a setup working with `netstandard1.0` support using `System.Linq` downgraded all the way from `4.3.0` to `4.0.0`.

4.3.0 does not work

4.1.0 does not work

4.0.0 does work.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq/4.1.0
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq/4.0.0

Comment: I'm in the same boat, is this really the solution or a workaround? Why does this work/why is this necessary?

Comment: It was something to do with string not being an char[] in the lower versions of netstandard. Cannot remember.